# How to fix small icons and text on Steam for MacOS?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos

Recently I opened up Steam and it suddenly became microscopic - text and images are tiny. The text on the left is about 4pt font size:

[image: Steam library interface but text and icons are really small]

I tried the standard debugging steps, restarting Steam, restarting the whole computer etc. Where is the setting to fix that?

I'm on MacOS 10.15 with a 15" monitor, the screenshot is of the full screen.

Comment: I'm unsure how Macs work, but maybe try fiddling with scaling and resolution settings of your computer. And check if Steam has similar options (I don't think it does, but unsure)

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to Ventura? Your image is showing that it's a 3360x1908 pixels (Which for small text is on par if it's being forced down to a 15 in screen making it almost unreadable). Check your display settings and see what the setting is for scale. Steam is likely respecting what you have set there. And there's a chance the upgrade "reset" your display settings. So it could be as simple as adjusting it to something else and then adjusting back.

Comment: @Sorean I'm on 10.15 still, don't want to brick my macbook

Comment: @Betydlig did you try toggling your display settings as suggested? It could have still been something with the changes of that recently with a steam update and not an OS update.

Comment: I too have this problem. About 5 days ago, suddenly my Steam library on Mac is 1/2 the size. Toggling resolution and scaling settings doesn't help. Changing Library > Display Size for UI elements doesn't help. EDIT - Literally seconds after my last comment, Steam updated and now it looks fine. Thank you, Valve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something very similar [was reported on a different forum](https://forum.zorin.com/t/steam-has-small-font/8218) about a year ago (September 2021), and was [self solved](https://forum.zorin.com/t/steam-has-small-font/8218/6) few days later:

> The problem was the fractional scale, i resolved the problem changing from 125% to 100% scale (and toggle off the fractional scale) and then steam and wine apps are more readable, and for the apps and system fonts that get too small in 100% scale, with the GNOME Tweaks put the system fonts scaling in 1,30 and the panel size from the zorin appearance from 48px to 64px.

Worth giving this a try in your case as well.

Comment: shouldn't that be easier? I mean it was normal for 7+ years